# Redux - API is being called multiple times (Redux Thunk)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using Next.js and Redux as a state management. Everything is working perfectly fine except one thing and that is API calls. What I mean by this is that API is being called multiple times even though I `dispatched` it just once. When I go and see in the network tab in Google Chrome, I see multiple calls being called.

I am also using Redux Thunk and Redux Toolkit:

#### store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import layoutSlice from "./layoutSlice";
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    layout: layoutSlice,
  },
});
```

#### layoutSlice

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:1337";

export const getHeaderData = createAsyncThunk(
  "layout/getHeaderData",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${BASE_URL}/api/navigations?populate=*&sort=id`
    );
    return response.data;
  }
);

export const getFooterData = createAsyncThunk(
  "layout/getFooterData",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${BASE_URL}/api/footers?populate[ContactForm][populate]=*&populate[Links][populate]=*&populate[Info][populate]=*`
    );
    return response.data;
  }
);

const initialState = {
  header: [],
  footer: [],
  isLoadingHeader: false,
  isLoadingFooter: false,
};

const layoutSlice = createSlice({
  name: "layout",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [getHeaderData.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isLoadingHeader = true;
    },
    [getHeaderData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.header = action.payload;
      state.isLoadingHeader = false;
    },
    [getHeaderData.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.isLoadingHeader = false;
    },
    [getFooterData.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isLoadingFooter = true;
    },
    [getFooterData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.footer = action.payload;
      state.isLoadingFooter = false;
    },
    [getFooterData.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.isLoadingFooter = false;
    },
  },
});

export default layoutSlice.reducer;
```

#### generalLayout (where the API is called)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Header, Footer } from "../components";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getHeaderData, getFooterData } from "../redux/layoutSlice";

const GeneralLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const { isLoadingHeader, isLoadingFooter } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.layout
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getHeaderData());
    dispatch(getFooterData());
  }, []);

  if (isLoadingHeader === true || isLoadingFooter === true) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default GeneralLayout;
```

I am also using Strapi (dont mind the query for the API call, it works for me so I do not think the problem is there, at least it should not be)

#### Network tab

[image]

Comment: Don't rely on the component rendering (useEffect empty dependency array) to decide if the data should be loaded. Instead wrap the dispatches in an if statement (within the useEffect) and check what you have in the redux store. If you don't have it in the store what you need, then load it. The reason for the double dispatches is probably that a parent component unmounts and then remounts, firing the useEffect twice.

Comment: @SzabóSebestyén I tried the conditional rendering in useEffect( ), but it wasn't calling the API anymore. I used redux persist to keep my state on reload, so, on every reload, useEffect( ) ran again and added the same data to the already present data. When I added the if...else statements, the data was gone

Comment: @Uzair_07 apparently useEffect is called twice in development. So it is intended. I was not aware of this. Check out user18821127's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of `useEffect`
In development, React strictmode calls all effects twice to catch any memory leaks and other issues.

> This only applies to development mode, production behavior is unchanged
> So you don't want to worry about it being called twice in production/build

From official React docs (beta at time of writing)

> If your Effect fetches something, the cleanup function should either abort the fetch or ignore its result:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;

  async function startFetching() {
    const json = await fetchTodos(userId);
    if (!ignore) {
      setTodos(json);
    }
  }

  startFetching();

  return () => {
    ignore = true;
  };
}, [userId]);
```

Read more [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data)

Answer (score 0):

You must add a dispatch to dependency of useEffect function..
make sure the peomise function receives  parameter as the informations you want to get or post.. And call the parameter inside axios func after APIurl.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).